# Liferay autologin filter triggers twice

Tags: authentication, liferay, servlet-filters, liferay-7, autologin

I am using Liferay DXP sp7 tomcat 8 bundle. In our DEV environment, the custom autologinfilter is triggering twice. This ends up running some web services that we need to run for user attributes twice which is not optimal or desired.

The code is deployed and the user auto login works. However, the code runs twice as the log.info messages are printed twice and the custom code we are trying to optimize, is run twice.

Is there a way to run the autologinfilter run only once? Any insight would be much appreciated.

**AutoLoginFilter code sample:**

> @Component(
>       immediate = true,
>       configurationPid = "com.custom.login.configuration.customLoginConfiguration"
>           )
>   public class CustomAutoLoginFilter implements AutoLogin {

```
@Override
public String[] login(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AutoLoginException {

    _log.info("in custom auto login filter " );

    try {
```

_configuration = _customLoginConfigurationRetriever.getConfiguration(companyId);
            //do custom logic
        } catch (Exception e) {
            _log.error("Exception in auto login process", e);

```
         return null;
    }
    // No errors thrown here

    // The user was added or already exists in Liferay
    String userId = String.valueOf(user.getUserId());
    String password = user.getPassword();
    String encrypted = Boolean.toString(false);
    String[] credentials = { userId, password, encrypted };

    return credentials;
}
```

> }
>
> @Reference
>       customLoginConfigurationRetriever _customLoginConfigurationRetriever;

```
private volatile customLoginConfiguration _configuration;
```

I don't see anything out of place in the web.xml and the liferay-web.xml and the filter/filter-mappings.

**Update:**
I found the correlation to the filter running twice. We are using system configuration for virtual instance specific configurations. When there are 2 entries in the System settings -> custom config being used, the auto login class triggers twice.

Any insight in how to just use system config and only run auto login once would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you create a component class?

Comment: yes, it is a component module. I added the declaration above to the code snippet.

Comment: can you try adding this "service = AutoLogin.class" in component declaration?

Comment: Ok, thanks, will do. Do you think that will make a difference to not running it twice?

Comment: Sorry not sure just observation, you can also try this method https://www.e-systems.tech/blog/-/blogs/autologin-in-liferay-7.

Comment: I tried the service = AutoLogin.class. This had no effect. Thanks.